# Handling Large Response In parts

Tags: php, ajax

I am making an ajax call to php like as

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php_scripts/work.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {count: count},
    success: function(d) {
        //prev html content eg <div>blah blah </div>
        var prevData = document.getElementById("result_of_duplicate_div").innerHTML;
        prevData += d;

        //updated content
        document.getElementById("result_of_duplicate_div").innerHTML = d;
    }
});
```

### PHP Code:

```
<?php
require 'FirePHPCore/fb.php';
ob_start();

//session_start();
//FB::log('Log message');
//FB::info('Info message');
//FB::warn('Warn message');
//FB::error('Error message');

if(isset($_POST['count'])){
    $fileCount = $_POST['count'];
    while($fileCount < 10){
        echo  $fileCount;
        sleep(3);
        $fileCount++;
    }
}else{
    FB::log('count is null');
}
```

This is just an example i was trying
I was expecting my webpage should first display 1 then 2 upto 9
but it printed 1 to 9 in one attempt.

In reality i will be using socket to communicate between java server and php client where server will process large data and give part by part response which can be displayed to end-user, so i sketch that problem in the above code, so can anyone help me to achieve this ?
thanks

Comment: You should pass the data in a json array and then use a timer javascript side to show first then second and then next.. The sleep might pause the script, but the succes is only called when the script has completed.. So you don't notice it..

Comment: timer in javascript for displaying parts like 1 after some delay 2 will not serve my purpose because my server code will give result in small small parts which i need to show to user how to achieve this sir, i mean i know how to do socket programming i m just asking concept for accepting small results every time server sends it and displaying it to user so that user will not feel like website has been hanged.